# One fixed pattern followed by any number of other patterns using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, regex-greedy

Requirement : I have following data to match with regEX. I need to get Name 1, Name 2, Name 3 and Name 4.

Some Conditions :

1. `$regex` need to consider that `Name` will always come after `<H2>Composition<\H2>`
2. There could be any number of `Name` i.e. It could happen that after `Composition` there is only one pattern say `Name1` or two pattern `Name1` and `Name2`.
3. At least one `Name` pattern will be present after Composition. So regex should be like "Composition is present then Name1 will be surely there"

Example:

```
 <H2>Composition</H2>
 <A href="/generics/levocetrizine-210129">Name 1</A>,
 <A href="/generics/paracetamol-210459">Name 2(500 mg)</A>,
 <A href="/generics/phenylephrine-hydrochloride-210494">Name 3</A>,
 <A href="/generics/ambroxol-hydrochloride-211798">Name 4</A></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

So far, I could only be able to get first `Name` i.e. `Name1` via following script. My script simply ignores rest of "Name" i.e. in above case, Name2, Name3 and Name4 are missing from my output.

```
[regex]$regex = 
@'
(?s).+?<H2>Composition</H2>.*?href="/generics/.*?">(.*?)</A>
'@
```

Comment: You're using the lazy operator `?` which stops at the first occurence of `</A>`.

Comment: If I remove it, it just gives me last "Name". In above case, Name4 only. I need all Names. Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4.

Comment: Can I do something like. ONE Instance of "Composition" followed by any number of Instance of "Name"

Comment: Required reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Gerenal rule of thumb: don't use regexes to parse HTML/XML. Use a parser for it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is much easier to solve with a XPath Expression or a little bit of C# against the [HTML Agility pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). [Regular Expressions are going to be a major pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), though in this case you might be able to make them work.

With the HTML Agility Pack it would be something like:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourString);

string xpath = "//H2[contains(text(), 'Composition')]/following-sibling::A[contains(@href, '/generics/']";

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string name = node.InnerText;
    string uri = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

Conversion to Powershell from this little C# snippet should not be hard.

Using Regex is going to be a pain in the long run, it's not meant to do HTML parsing or parsing of a structured document like HTML or XML.

if you really want to take the **awful, bad, not good, horrible, regex** way, try something like this:

```
(?i)<h2>composition</h2>(?:(?:(?!<a).*)<a href="/generics/[^"]+">(?<name>(?!</a).*)</A>)*
```

And use the .NET regex capability to grab the Captures:

```
([regex]$regex).Match("$content").Groups['name'].Captures
```